# Update the response without null value

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have the following entities provided below,

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "creation_on" ,updatable = false)
    private Date creationOn;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "state")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmployeeStates employeeState;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;


}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "address")
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "zip")
    private int zip;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Employee employee;

}
```

The POST call is provided below,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDto employeeDto) {

    try{
        Employee employee = employeeService.createEmployee(employeeDto);

        if(employee != null){

            return new ResponseEntity<>(employee, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
            MessageConstant.EMPLOYEE_NOT_CREATE_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {

        log.error(MessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG + ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getInternalServerError(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

When the response is coming, its below:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "creationOn": "2021-02-27T15:05:23.585+00:00",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "phoneNumber": "string",
  "age": 0,
  "employeeState": "ADDED",
  "address": {
    "id": 3,
    "street": "string",
    "state": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "zip": 0,
    "employee": null
  }
}
```

How do I not see the "employee": null in the response?

Comment: If its null you get a 422 http status code and the EMPLOYEE_NOT_CREATE_MSG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` or `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` on your `Entity` classes.

Like

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Employee {

}
```

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` -
Value that indicates that only properties with null value,or what is considered empty, are not to be included.Definition of emptiness is data type specific; see belowfor details on actual handling.

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` - Value that indicates that only properties with non-nullvalues are to be included.

Answer (score 0):

I need to ignore JSON value from the child entity as below:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
@JsonIgnore
private Employee employee;
```

This makes all fine.